# Splitting a string into words and keeping delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

**I want to split up a string (sentence) in an array of words and keep the delimiters.**

---

I have found and I am currently using this regex for this:

`[^.!?\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?!['"]?\s|$)[^.!?]*)*[.!?]?['"]?(?=\s|$)`

*An explanation can be found here: http://regex101.com/*

This works exactly as I want it to and effectively makes a string like

`This is a sentence.`

To an array of

`["This", "is", "a", "sentence."]`

The problem here is that it does **not** include *spaces nor newlines*. I want the string to be parsed as words as it already does but I also want the *corresponding space and or newline character to belong to the previous word*.

I have read about *positive lookahead* that should look for future characters (space and or newline) but still take them into account when extracting the word. Although this might be the solution I have failed to implement it.

If it makes any difference I am using JavaScript and the following code:

```
//save the regex -- g modifier to get all matches
var reg =  /[^.!?\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?!['"]?\s|$)[^.!?]*)*[.!?]?['"]?(?=\s|$)/g;

//define variable for holding matches
var matches;
//loop through each match
while(matches = reg.exec(STRING_HERE)){
    //the word without spaces or newlines
    console.log(matches[0]);
}
```

The code **works** but as I said, it does **not** include *spaces and newline characters*.

Comment: Provide an example to replicate this `The problem here is that it does not include spaces nor newlines.` problem.

Comment: Ditch that ugly regex, use split, and add newlines manually:
`"This is a sentence".split(" ").map(function(word){ return word+" "; })`

Comment: @PSkocik - that will also add space after the last word, which is not originally there.

Comment: @Chris It's not like its super hard to do remove it from the last one. My point is, I don't think this is a good use of regexes.

Comment: I agree with @PSkocik. That was exactly what I was thinking while writing my answer. Sometimes simple tools just get the job done.

Comment: Your regex matches the entire test string. How does it do split?

Comment: Basically your regex is this `[^.!?\s][^.!?]*(?=\s|$)` It finds a letter, then matches all the way to the end of the string `$` if there is no `[.!?]` in the way.

Answer (score 5):

Yo can try something simpler:

```
str.split(/\b(?!\s)/);
```

However, note non word characters (e.g. full stop) will be considered another word:

```
"This is a sentence.".split(/\b(?!\s)/);
// [ "This ", "is ", "a ", "sentence", "." ]
```

To fix that, you can use a character class with the characters that shouldn't begin another word:

```
str.split(/\b(?![\s.])/);
```

Comment: Just like in the answer PSocik provided did the first tests I've done proves that this code did work for what I am trying to achieve, will come back later to accept as an answer if so.

Answer (score 1):

```
function split_string(str){    
   var arr = str.split(" ");
   var last_i = arr.length - 1;
   for(var i=0; i<last_i; i++){
       arr[i]+=" ";
   }
   return arr;
 }
```

Comment: As pointed out in the comments to the post I might have looked upon this task in the wrong way which made me look for an overcomplicated approach. The first tests I've done proves that this code did work for what I am trying to achieve, will come back later to accept as an answer if so.

Comment: After some further testing I can see that it does work but that for all words that contains a newline, it combines the first word, the newline and the next word.

Sample jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/r71msxrh/4/

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as this:

```
var sentence = 'This is a sentence.';
sentence = sentence.split(' ').join(' ||');
sentence = sentence.split('\n').join('\n||');
var matches = sentence.split('||');
```

Note that I use 2 pipes as a delimiter, but ofcourse you can use anything as long as it's unique.

Also note that I only split \n as a newline, but you may add \r\n or whatever you want to split as well.

Answer (score 0):

### General Solution

To keep the delimiters conjoined in the results, the regex needs to be a zero-width match. In other words, the regex can be thought of as matching the point between a delimiter and non-delimiter, rather than matching the delimiters themselves. This can be achieved with zero-width matching expressions, matching before, at, or after the split point (at most one each); let's call these `A`, `B`, and `C`. Sometimes a single sub-expression will do it, others you'll need two; offhand, I can't think of a case where you'd need three.

Not only look-aheads but [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in general are the perfect candidates for this purpose: lookbehinds (`(?<=...)`) to match before the split point, and lookaheads (`(?=...)`) after. That's the essence of this approach. Positive or negative lookarounds can be used. The one pitfall is that lookbehinds are relatively new to JS regexes, so not all [browsers](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) or other JS engines will support them (current versions of Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge, and node.js do; Safari does not). If you need to support a JS engine that doesn't support lookbehinds, you might still be able to write & use a regex that matches at-and-before (`BC`).

To have the delimiters appear at the end of each match, put them in `A`. To have them at the start, in `C`. Fortunately, JS regexes do not place [restrictions on lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind), so simply wrapping the delimiter regex in the positive lookaround markers should be all that's required for delimiters. If the delimiters aren't so simple (i.e. context-sensitive), it might take a little more work to write the regex, which doesn't need to match the entire delimiter.

Paired with the delimiter pattern, you'll need to write a pattern that matches the start (for `C`) or end (for `A`) of the non-delimiter. This step is likely the one that will require the most additional work.

The at-split-point match, `B`
will often (always?) be a simple [boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html), such as `\b`.

### Specific Solution

If spaces are the only delimiters, and they're to appear at the end of each match, the delimiter pattern would be `(?<=\s)`, in `A`. However, there are some cases not covered in the problem description. For example, should words separated by only punctuation (e.g. "x.y") be split? Which side of a split point should quotation marks and hyphens appear, if any? Should they count as punctuation? Another option for the delimiter is to match (after) all non-word characters, in which case `A` would be `(<?=\W)`.

Since the split-point is at a word boundary, `B` could be `\b`.

Since the start of a match is a word character, `(?=\w)` will suffice for `C`.

Any two of those three should suffice. One that is perhaps clearest in meaning (and splits at the most points) is `/(<?=\W)(?=\w)/`, which can be translated as "split at the start of each word". `\b` could be added, if you find it more understandable, though it has no functional affect: `/(<?=\W)\b(?=\w)/`.

Note Oriol's excellent solutions are given by `B`=`\b` and (`C`=`(?!\s)` or `C`=`(?![\s.])`).

#### Additional

As a point of interest, there would be a simpler solution for this particular case if JS regexes supported [TCL word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html#tcl): `\m` matches only at the start of a word, so `str.split(/\m/)` would split exactly at the start of each word. (`\m` is equivalent to `(<?=\W)(?=\w)`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the whitespace after the word, the regex `\S+\s*` should work.

```js
const s = `This is a sentence.
This is another sentence.`;

console.log(s.match(/\S+\s*/g))
```