# Separate sentence with special characters into words including spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I want to separate a sentence **with special characters** into words **keeping the spaces**. Like so:

```
"la sílaba tónica es la penúltima".split(...regex...)
```

to:

```
["la ", "sílaba ", "tónica ", "es ", "la ", "penúltima"]
    ↑                     ↑      ↑      ↑
  space                 space  space  space
```

I've tried with a modified version of this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26184632/2083117

With the code from that answer:

```
"la sílaba tónica es la penúltima".split(/\b(?![\s.])/)
```

Result:

```
["la ", "s", "í", "laba ", "t", "ó", "nica ", "es ", "la ", "pen", "ú", "ltima"]
              ↑                  ↑                                  ↑
```

Those special characters shouldn't split the word.

My version simply adding the special characters I want to keep (`.áéíóúñ,:;?`):

```
"la sílaba tónica es la penúltima".split(/\b(?![\s.áéíóúñ,:;?])/)
```

Result:

```
["la ", "sí", "laba ", "tó", "nica ", "es ", "la ", "penú", "ltima"]
          ↑              ↑                              ↑
```

Now the characters are included but the word is braking after them.

What would be the right regular expression for this?

Comment: What if two words are separated by two spaces? Should two spaces be preserved? What is the use case for your spaces at the end of the token?

Comment: @de1 The use case for the spaces is to turn this into words as separated span elements so I can have different interactions per word. Spaces should be part of the word so interactions from one word to the other are smooth. In this use case I never have 2 spaces, so it's not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to match `\S+\s*` instead of split.

```js
var result = "la sílaba tónica es la penúltima".match(/\S+\s*/gi);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Since it completely solves my problem I accepted Mohammed Ashafaq answer but I would still like to know how to do this properly using RegEx. What would be the way to write the .match() on a sencence?

Comment: After the edit, this is a much more clear answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```js
let splitArray = "la sílaba tónica es la penúltima".split(" ")

let splitArrayWithSpaces =  splitArray.map((item, index ) => {
  if(index!== splitArray.length-1) return (item+ " ")
  else return item
})

console.log(splitArrayWithSpaces)
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine for my case, thank you!. I was too focused on solving it with RegEx. It can be even a bit shorter using the third argument for map (the array) and using a ternary operator for the item logic.
`"...".split(' ').map( (word, i, array) => { return i !== array.length-1 ? \`${word} \` : word })`

Comment: I think schorsch solution is much better than my solution @lan.w. If possible please accept  schorsch answer.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. For my own use case I will use your solution as it makes my life easier later. But I agree, for my question as I presented, schorsch's solution is much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This `a-z\xC0-\xff` selects chars and diacritics. I split it by `/[^a-z\xC0-\xff]/`. Then I add the space.

Alternatively you can split by `/[\s]/`

```js
let test = "la sílaba tónica es la penúltima".split(/[^a-z\xC0-\xff]/)
for(let i=0; i < test.length; i++){test[i]+= " ";}
console.log(test)
```